# Split single String column to multiple columns in Spark-Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as:

```
+----+--------------------------+
|city|Types                     |
+----+--------------------------+
|BNG |school                    |
|HYD |school,restaurant         |
|MUM |school,restaurant,hospital|
+----+--------------------------+
```

I wanna split **Types** column in multiple cols with **','**.

The problem is column size is not fixed so I not getting how to do it.

I saw another related question in pyspark but I wanna do it in spark-scala and not pyspark

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to split the `Types` column into multiple columns when the length of the types are not fixed? Because in that way many fields in the desired output dataframe would be `null`. Wouldn't it be better to have as many records for the same `city` as types in the `Types` columns? Or even better an RDD with key-value pairs?

Comment: Just use an array as a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to address the irregular size in the column is to tweak the representation.

for example:

```
val data = Seq(("BNG", "school"),("HYD", "school,res"),("MUM", "school,res,hos")).toDF("city","types")

+----+--------------+
|city|         types|
+----+--------------+
| BNG|        school|
| HYD|    school,res|
| MUM|school,res,hos|
+----+--------------+

data.withColumn("isSchool", array_contains(split(col("types"),","), "school")).withColumn("isRes", array_contains(split(col("types"),","), "res")).withColumn("isHos", array_contains(split(col("types"),","), "hos"))

+----+--------------+--------+-----+-----+
|city|         types|isSchool|isRes|isHos|
+----+--------------+--------+-----+-----+
| BNG|        school|    true|false|false|
| HYD|    school,res|    true| true|false|
| MUM|school,res,hos|    true| true| true|
+----+--------------+--------+-----+-----+
```